# Query doesn´t work with a variable from array as condition

Tags: php, laravel

i´m trying to do the follow query:

```
foreach($arraytodos as $array){
        $vptn = $array;
        echo $vptn;
        $patron = DB::table('patrones')->where('ptn', $vptn)->first();
}
var_dump($patron);
```

the result is: 090010080020NULL

The `$arraytodos` content is:

```
[0]=>090,
[1]=>010,
[2]=>080,
[3]=>020.
```

If I put the number `090`, for example, as condition it returns me the object, but it doesn´t work as variable. I don´t understand.

Comment: Maybe your octal `090` is converted to int and that value is not found in DB?

Comment: `$a = 090;"` returns `PHP Parse error:  Invalid numeric literal on line 1`; `$a = (int)'090';` returns `90`; You have to set correct type of variable before check it in database.

Comment: ok, but i need to keep the data as a char type... the problem is when i merge two arrays before that. There are any way to mantain the data as char??

Comment: The real question is if the last item in the array exists in the database. If `ptn == 020` does not exist you will always get `null` for `$patron` as it is the last value it gets set to.

Comment: Sorry, exactly, Alex, that was the problem, i didn´t have ptn = 020 in the database yet...